# How to configure my Fedora 32 to resume from hibernation/suspend with the power button?

Tags: linux, fedora, hibernate, suspend, acpi

I'm trying to enable PWRB on my `/proc/acpi/wakeup` but it is not even listed as an option:

```
[root@vatican00 ~]# cat /proc/acpi/wakeup 
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.1
GPP2      S4    *disabled
GPP3      S4    *disabled
GPP4      S4    *disabled
GPP5      S4    *disabled
GPP6      S4    *disabled
GPP7      S4    *disabled
GPP8      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:03.1
X161      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:09:00.0
GPP9      S4    *disabled
X162      S4    *disabled
GPPA      S4    *disabled
GPPB      S4    *disabled
GPPC      S4    *disabled
GPPD      S4    *disabled
GPPE      S4    *disabled
GPPF      S4    *disabled
GP10      S4    *disabled
GP11      S4    *disabled
GP12      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
GP13      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:0b:00.3
GP30      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.2
GP31      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.3
PS2K      S3    *disabled
PS2M      S3    *disabled
BXBR      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.2
```

Yet, no dmesg I see the following:

```
[    0.572572] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.572608] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
```

How can I enable my PC to wake up using the power button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may answer you question regarding the issue:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1795422

Here's a link to the same issue and the article above is what was provided:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/ggdpwj/hibernation_not_working_in_fedora_32/

Comment: Using dracut to add resume to my hibernation solved the issue for me. Thanks.